# Engaging in a puzzle without a guidance of a leader while simultaneously being a component of that puzzle

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, activities

I have done couple of activities and experienced how interestingly students are engaging. At the end I explained the Mathematical concepts related to the activities. Here I'm suggesting two of those,

Engaging Group Activities for Students:

1. **Tower of Hanoi Challenge:**

   - Gather a group of ten students with varying heights.
   - Assign each student a position in front of a Tower of Hanoi puzzle without verbal communication.
   - Each student in front independently decides on their move, representing the discs' movement without communicating
   - The challenge encourages strategic thinking and problem-solving without direct leadership.
2. **Fifteen Number Puzzle:**

   - Create a 4x4 grid on the floor and position 16 students one in each square.
   - Fifteen students wear caps numbered from  1 to 15 while one remains uncapped.
   - Only students adjacent to the uncapped individual can communicate with the uncapped student and interchange position with the uncapped student.
   - Through collaborative decision-making, students must rearrange themselves to solve the puzzle without having a leader.

These activities not only foster teamwork and critical thinking but also provide an opportunity to explore mathematical
concepts in a practical, hands-on manner. I would like to know what other activities are there to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: We can encourage students to either download the apps and play the game or purchase the puzzle set to engage with the material. However, the most effective approach is to facilitate it as a collective human activity where everyone is actively involved, without the need for a designated leader to guide them. This way, we can maximize the benefits of practical engagement for all participants.